# ReferenceError: PDFJS is not defined Asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, pdf.js

I'm trying to display a pdf using `canvas` and PDF.JS Stable v.2.2.228 but when I execute my webform it shows this error in the console: **ReferenceError: PDFJS is not defined**. 
I read something about the global PDFJS object being removed but I can't find the correct syntax *[Kinda new in JS]*. **Any suggestion is very appreciated**

I was following this example in case is needed : https://usefulangle.com/post/20/pdfjs-tutorial-1-preview-pdf-during-upload-wih-next-prev-buttons

**Js code:**

```
   function showPDF(pdf_url) {

            PDFJS.getDocument({ url: pdf_url }).then(function (pdf_doc) {
                __PDF_DOC = pdf_doc;
                __TOTAL_PAGES = __PDF_DOC.numPages;

                // Show the first page
                showPage(1);
            }).catch(function (error) {
                // If error re-show the upload button

                alert(error.message);
            });;

        }

        function showPage(page_no) {
            __PAGE_RENDERING_IN_PROGRESS = 1;
            __CURRENT_PAGE = page_no;

            __PDF_DOC.getPage(page_no).then(function (page) {
                // As the canvas is of a fixed width we need to set the scale of the viewport accordingly
                var scale_required = __CANVAS.width / page.getViewport(1).width;

                // Get viewport of the page at required scale
                var viewport = page.getViewport(scale_required);

                // Set canvas height
                __CANVAS.height = viewport.height;

                var renderContext = {
                    canvasContext: __CANVAS_CTX,
                    viewport: viewport
                };

                page.render(renderContext).then(function () {
                    __PAGE_RENDERING_IN_PROGRESS = 0;

                    // Show the canvas and hide the page loader
                    $("#pdf-canvas").show();
                });
            });
        }

        function ValidateFileUpload() {
            var fuData = document.getElementById('FileUpload1');
            var FileUploadPath = fuData.value;

            //To check if user upload any file
            if (FileUploadPath == '') {
                alert("Por favor subir un archivo");

            } else {
                var Extension = FileUploadPath.substring(
                    FileUploadPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();

                //The file uploaded is an image

                if (Extension == "png" || Extension == "jpeg" || Extension == "jpg" || Extension == "gif" || Extension == "jfif") {

                    // To Display
                    if (fuData.files && fuData.files[0]) {
                        var reader = new FileReader();

                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                            $('#ImgPreview').attr('src', e.target.result);
                            //document.getElementById('ImgPreview').files[0].name;
                           var nombre= document.getElementById('ImgPreview').files[0].name;
                            document.querySelector('#LblFileupload').innerText = nombre;
                        }

                        reader.readAsDataURL(fuData.files[0]);
                    }

                }

                else if (Extension == "pdf") {

                    var __PDF_DOC,
                        __CURRENT_PAGE,
                        __TOTAL_PAGES,
                        __PAGE_RENDERING_IN_PROGRESS = 0,
                        __CANVAS = $('#pdf-canvas').get(0),
                        __CANVAS_CTX = __CANVAS.getContext('2d');

                    showPDF(URL.createObjectURL($("#FileUpload1").get(0).files[0]));

                }


                //The file upload is NOT an image
                else {
                    alert("Solo se aceptan archivos en formato .JPG - .PNG - .JPEG - .GIF - .JFIF");

                }
            }
        }
```

**HTML :**

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" accept="image/*"   onchange="return ValidateFileUpload()" Visible="true" />
<asp:Image ID="ImgPreview" runat="server" Height="600px" Width="500px" />
 <canvas id="pdf-canvas" width="400"> </canvas>
```

Comment: Do you have the latest PDF.js?

Comment: Yes, is Stable v2.2.228 [link](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/#download) here it is

Comment: Also have you tried using `pdfjsLib.getDocument()` instead of `pdfjs.getDocument()`?

Comment: it works but now it shows me this error in the console : __CANVAS is not defined

Comment: What did you do to make it work? And at which line does it show that `__CANVAS` is not defined?

Comment: After all i change the javascript code and now is working fine, thank you so much King11 for the help

Comment: Sure, no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `PDFJS` to `pdfjsLib`. Also you should try adding the lines `var __CANVAS = $('#pdf-canvas').get(0);` and `var __CANVAS_CTX = __CANVAS.getContext('2d');` under `__CURRENT_PAGE = page_no;` in that function because you're not initializing those variables before you try to call and use them. Also you need to add var in front of the other two items you're using in that function at the top.

So it should look like:

```
pdfjsLib.getDocument(URL.createObjectURL($("#FileUpload1").get(0).files[0])).then(doc => {
                        console.log("This file has " + doc._pdfInfo.numPages + "pages");

                        doc.getPage(1).then(page => {
                            var myCanvas = document.getElementById('pdf-canvas');
                            var context = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

                            var viewport = page.getViewport(1);
                            myCanvas.width = viewport.width;
                            myCanvas.height = viewport.height;

                            page.render({
                                canvasContext: context,
                                viewport : viewport
                            }
                            );
                        });

                    });
```